# WordPress - Show no articles if author is not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

On my site I have successfully been able to show authors the links to their specific articles and no other articles. However, if not logged in, they see a list of all articles in the site of that post-type. I want to leave that space blank if the user is not logged in. I don't want to lock down the page because instead of the article link there will be a link to generate an article. Here is what I have so far...how can I return nothing if the author is not logged in?

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'team_fundraiser',
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'author' => $user_id
);                       

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$team_link .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ). '">'. esc_html( get_the_title() ) . '</a>';

endwhile;

echo $team_link;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just check if the user is logged in?

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo $team_link; //can place around this or the query itself
}
```

You can go one step further and check if the user that is logged in had the correct privileges

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('manage_options')  ) {
    echo $team_link;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Stevo. That was the simple solution I was looking for.